# Display image in a UIImageView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I do not wants use a picker view to pick a image. I have image name `abc.JPG` which is in iPhone image library, can I programmatically fetch this image and put on `UIImageView`?

Comment: As far as i understand, we cannot give names to the images in the iPhone/iPad albums app.
can u elaborate more on ur problem statement?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674597/dispay-local-image-in-uiimageview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image isn't in your application resource and you don't want to use UIImagePickerController then you can use ALAssetsLibrary to fetch the images on user albums or camera roll.

Take a look here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

```
   UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.JPG"];

[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

or if you have already uiimageview with name myImage then just write:

```
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.JPG"];
```

Comment: .thanks for reply.  my image is not in my application resource folder . Image is present in simulator Library. can this code work fine for that

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [UIImageView alloc] init];
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.JPG"];
```

Comment: To the gentleman that edited my post: if I wanted to release the `UIImageView` I would. For simplicity I am assuming the op is using ARC. For the person that -1, at least have the **common sense** to explain why.

Comment: thanks for reply. my image is not in my application resource folder . Image is present in simulator Library. can this code work fine for that

Comment: At least in iOS 6 this method is actually called `imageNamed:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/) tutorial.

Even if you don't want to, I think you have to use `UIImagePickerViewController` to pick the image, otherwise the image will be picked from Resources in your project.